# How many different Kid Icarus AR cards are there?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Kid Icarus AR cards all have a number on the bottom left (e.g. AKDP-001). These seem to be continuous. The highest one I have is AKDP-375, and I've heard that one of the rare cards Nintendo Power gave out is AKDP-404.

How many different cards are there total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to a fan database there are 406 known cards, with numbers going up to 412.](http://ar.essh.co/decks/kid-icarus?wctstart=401) There are several gaps in the list which may or may not be filled later.

Answer (score 1):

I just completed the idol collections and apparently, there are 404 available idols. Meaning there could be 404 different AR cards for us to scan.

Comment: What's the last idol in your list? Mine is "Dark Pit (Flying)", which is AKDP-407. If there's only 404, I wonder what numbers are missing...

Comment: i now have 405 and i now that ithre is more

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would seem that there is a card for each weapon, character, and idol. I'd assume that there are hundreds, if not thousands, of different cards.

Comment: Weapons and characters _are_ idols. It doesn't really answer the question though, it just changes it to "How many idols are there?"

Answer (score -1):

The official website says there are 20 in total.

http://kidicarus.nintendo.com/uprising/explore-the-game/where-to-find-arcards.html

Comment: The site says you get six out of a selection of 20 when you buy the game. Given that I have about 180 unique cards so far, the answer is definitely not 20.